# Project Android with Custom Library + Global var

Tags: android, global, var

I am creating a book and I'm interested in globalizing variables (objects).

In one project I can do with Singletone:
But if I use it in my library and give it a value, if in my project I consult the value is always 0.

**LIBRARY:**

```
public class Globals{
   private static Globals instance;

   // Global variable
   private int data;

   // Restrict the constructor from being instantiated
   private Globals(){}

   public void setData(int d){
       this.data=d;
   }
   public int getData(){
     return this.data;
   }

   public static synchronized Globals getInstance(){
     if(instance==null){
         instance=new Globals();
     }
     return instance;
   }
   /*Then write your methods here*/
      public void yourMethod(){}
}
```

**LIBRARY: Class ExampleLib**

```
Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
        g.setData(120));
```

**Myproject**

```
Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
        System.out.println(g.getData()); // show 0
```

Comment: check if the global is really the same

Comment: Yes, is the same. In myproject i have: import my.library.Globals;

Comment: I mean at runtime, with a debugger or logging, do they refer to same object **in memory**?